# how to hide UIButton in UIViewController in IOS?

Tags: uibutton

As shown in screen shot i have login page, which contains login and registration buttons, after registration over i need hide the registration button.
 [click here to view screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAg70.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to hide it programmatically.You can have two option.

1. ButtonOutlet.hidden = YES;

OR Other thing

2. in interface builder set Hidden

   [image]

Comment: after registration over, In registration page ,after i click on submit button ,registration button hide on login page please see screen shot once .

Comment: From  Registration page pass one Variable to Login page and set condition in login page

Comment: if (Registration){

 ButtonOutlet.Hidden = YES;
}else{

 ButtonOutlet.Hidden = NO;
} set in ViewWillApear in Register page

Comment: not yet worked,can u please make it understandable .

Comment: i can't write whole code for you. i can only provide suggestion.

Comment: @sanandiyavipul is right... pass variable to login page and set condition to hide button in if else condition or if you don't want to pass variable then you can set value in NSUserDefault.